# Пересчитывается ли условие цикла после каждой итерации?

Tags: c, циклы, условия

Допустим, у меня есть цикл, в условии которого что нибудь вычисляется.

```
int x = ...;
for (int M = 1; M < f(x); M++) {
...    //x не изменяется
}
```

Будет ли функция в условии вычислять значение после каждой итерации цикла, или компиляторы достаточно умные чтобы просто запомнить значение которое получилось в первый раз.
Желательно (но не обязательно) дать ответ с ссылкой на какуюнибудь документацию или стандарт.

Comment: обосновать не могу, посему только комментарий... Думаю, пересчитывается, так как обычно нет никаких гарантий, что значение ,возвращаемое функцией `f(x)` не изменится

Comment: `f(x)` вычисляется на каждой итерации. Однако, **если** компилятор сможет доказать, что на каждой итерации `f(x)` вернёт одно и тоже значение и не произведёт никаких побочных эффектов, то он вправе вычислить функцию всего один раз.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно, пересчитывается.

Оптимизатор может выбросить пересчет, если функция простая и не меняет своего значения во время работы цикла, так что компилятор в состоянии это понять.

Comment: Компилятор может также развернуть цикл в последовательные итерации.

Comment: @0andriy Но если при этом функция меняет значение - она будет вычисляться на каждой итерации. Потому что главный принцип оптимизации - что измененный код все равно будет давать все те же результаты, что и неоптимизированный. Так что ваше замечание тут непонятно к чему.